# Como desabilitar o chatbot do DialogFlow integrado ao WhatsApp para um determinado número de telefone?

Tags: chatbot

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot com DialogFlow integrado ao WhatsApp.

Meu chatbot deve somente interagir com os números de celulares cadastrados no meu banco de dados.

Atualmente eu uso o respond.io que me permite bloquear o chatbot quando há intenção do usuario em chamar o atendente humano, mas venho tendo dificuldade em bloquear um número em que nem fez contato com o bot.

É possivel desabilitar o chatbot do DialogFlow integrado ao Wpp dado um número de telefone?

Comment: O Dialogflow **não** oferece integração nativa para Whatsapp. Eu imagino que você esteja usando a respond.io para fazer essa integração. A funcionalidade que você citou também parece ser muito específica dessa ferramenta, então eu sugiro [acionar o suporte da empresa](https://respond.io/contact/) pra te ajudar com seu problema.